# Qchart, legend()->setGeometry does not work

Tags: c++, qt, qchart

I followed qt documentation https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.11/qtcharts-legend-example.html to detach the legend from the chart and set the detached legend dimensions

```
legend->detachFromChart();
m_chart->legend()->setBackgroundVisible(true);
m_chart->legend()->setBrush(QBrush(QColor(128, 128, 128, 128)));
m_chart->legend()->setPen(QPen(QColor(192, 192, 192, 192)));
m_chart->legend()->setGeometry(QRectF(80, 50, 100, 180));
```

m_chart->legend()->setGeometry(QRectF(80, 50, 100, 180)) does not work.
the first two arguments works. The position of the legend is (80, 50). However, the last two arguments does not work. The width of the legend is not 100, and the height of the legend is not 180.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `update()` function of `QLegend` after setting geometry:

```
m_chart->legend()->update();
```

Comment: i added m_chart->legend()->update(), but width and height of the legend are not changed

Answer (score 0):

Update legend after setting the geometry of the legend.
m_chart->legend()->update().

Important note: set legend's geometry after  adding the lineseries
. this is worked for me .  When we set properties of legend & chart  before adding the lineseries, it won't work. Even in some case, it leads to application crash.